# Only stuff part executing in dynamic pivot query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have a dynamic pivot query in Stored Procedure using SQL Server 2008.

**Example**

```
 create proc testing 
 @tablename varchar(10),
 @col varchar(10)

 AS

 Declare @cols nvarchar(max),
         @query nvarchar(max)

 SET @cols = N'SELECT STUFF((SELECT '','' + QUOTENAME('+ @col +')
                from ' + @ViewName + '
                group by ' + @col + '
                  order by ' + @col + '
        FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE
        ).value(''.'', ''NVARCHAR(MAX)'') 
    ,1,1,'''')'

 execute(@cols)

 set @query = 'SELECT '+ @cols + '
        From
        (
            SELECT ' + @col + '
            from ' + @tablename + '
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            count(' + @col +')
            for ' + @col + ' in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

 exec sp_executesql @query;

 Go
```

Calling Function :

```
 execute testing @tablename = 'test1',@col = 'item'
```

**Note** Getting executed only `@cols` that is `STUFF` but not getting executed `@query`. I am not getting where I am going wrong.

Comment: What do you mean you are "not getting executed @ query"? Also, you need to wrap your column and table variable in quotename in the second query to help avoid sql injection.

Comment: @Sean Lange,  Yup! I got it. Thank you so much